# How to call a function on a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I am having to do:

```
$sourceElement['description'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($sourceElement['description']);
```

I want to avoid that redundant mention of the variable name. I tried:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(&$sourceElement['description']);
```

and

```
call_user_func('htmlspecialchars_decode', &$sourceElement['description']);
```

That did not work. Is this possible in PHP? Call a function *on* a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on function. `htmlspecialchars_decode()` returns the result, it doesn't modify the original variable. And you can do nothing about it.

Comment: I dont see why any of the other answers are better alternatives than just accepting how PHP works. +1 for not posting any unnecessary 'workarounds'.

Answer (score 7):

You could create your own wrapper function that takes the variable by reference:

```
function html_dec(&$str) {$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);}
```

Then call:

```
html_dec($sourceElement['description']);
```

Comment: Great workaround and info, thanks. I accepted the other one because of the added info about native behavior (*sigh* which got edited out later).

Comment: ... And then I make new functions like this for all PHP functions which return values, that I want to use? In that case its probably better to find another language...

Answer (score 3):

The *correct* solution would be to include that "redundant" variable mention. It's far more readable, and far less confusing that way.

```
$sourceElement['description'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($sourceElement['description']);
```

Your way of thinking is good though, you're thinking how to shorten your code, like a true lazy programmer =)

Answer (score 2):

Most functions in PHP are immutable in mature, i.e. they don't modify the arguments you pass into them. This has a few advantages, one of them being able to use their return value in expressions without side effects.

Here's a generic wrapper you could use to mimic mutable behaviour for any function that takes a single argument:

```
function applyFn(&$s, $fn)
{
    return $s = $fn($s);
}

applyFn($sourceElement['description'], 'htmlspecialchars_decode');

applyFn($sourceElement['description'], 'trim'); // trim string
```

Mileage may vary :)

Comment: Nice! Just afraid I might get into trouble with PHP functions that already take pointers... are there any such at all? Okay, redundant question, I guess I can just check the manual before using this on any function.

Comment: Yes it should be used with care :)